# Reason for difference between two parts of code to be traced

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, pyqt, compare

The code, that does not work is this one: (Just consider the Note-part; Main() is only for creating the systrayicon (which was at first implemented with the win32gui because of tkinter, but in qt it's much less code. I know that it is bad to mix those toolkits/frameworks).

```
from tkinter import Tk,Menu,TOP,Frame,X,NO,BOTH,YES,BOTTOM
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Note():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        print("Note has been created, but is not being displayed. Why? \n If Exit is clicked, it shows.")

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.notes=[]
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False);

        self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("J:\\python\\SimpleNotes.ico"), self.app)
        self.menu = QMenu()

        self.newWindow = self.menu.addAction("new Note")
        self.separator = self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.exitAction = self.menu.addAction("Exit")

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.newWindow.triggered.connect(self.newNote)
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.trayIcon.show()

        self.app.exec()

    def newNote(self):
        print("Create new note entry has been clicked")
        note=Note()
        #note.show() #because note is of Tk, it gots no show()
        self.notes.append(note)

    def close(self):
        self.trayIcon.hide()
        self.app.exit()
        print("Exit menu entry has been clicked")

Main()
```

The code that does work is this one: (I only replaced the Note() part, now with Qt instead of tkinter, and made the note show cause of Qt)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Note(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Note,self).__init__()
        self.w=QWidget()
        self.setWindowTitle("Note")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.notes=[]
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False);

        self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("J:\\python\\SimpleNotes.ico"), self.app)
        self.menu = QMenu()

        self.newWindow = self.menu.addAction("new Note")
        self.separator = self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.exitAction = self.menu.addAction("Exit")

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.newWindow.triggered.connect(self.newNote)
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.trayIcon.show()

        self.app.exec()

    def newNote(self):
        print("Create new note entry has been clicked")
        note=Note()
        note.show()
        self.notes.append(note)

    def close(self):
        self.trayIcon.hide()
        self.app.exit()
        print("Exit menu entry has been clicked")

Main()
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: The question is, why do the windows in the first code example only appear if i quit the systrayicon, and in the second code example, it works as intended and the created windows appear immediately?

Comment: @user2366975: please put an actual question in your question; don't assume people who are willing to answer are also willing to dig through all the comments.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought the part "to be traced" in the title implies that i can't figure out where the window is not created. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the tkinter window isn't displaying is because you aren't calling the `mainloop` method of the `Tk` instance. Windows are only drawn on the screen in response to an event, and events only get processed when the event loop is running (and `mainloop` is what starts the event loop)

In your question you wrote:

> I know that it is bad to mix those toolkits/frameworks

It's not so much that it's *bad* per se. It's more like it's impossible. Not truly, literally, impossible, just likely considerably harder and more error-prone to do than is worth the effort to do it.

Both (well, any) GUI toolkits require an event loop to run, and the two event loops are incompatible with each other. Even if you managed to merge the two, the windows in one toolkit have no way to interact with the windows of the other.

Comment: Okay thanks, the problem did also occur with win32gui modul for the systray instead of the qt-part. And I am not sure about the mainloop, the whole programm runs in IDLE without a mainloop in code, because I think Idle provides its own. I'll give it a try anyway, thanks!